# Duplicate tag basic-authentication and http-basic-authentication

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

1. [basic-authentication](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/basic-authentication) 63 questions, 1 follower, no wiki
2. [http-basic-authentication](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/http-basic-authentication) 10 questions, no follower, no wiki

Gotta say I would have expected the tag to be `http-basic-auth`.

Comment: Basic authentication is not limited to HTTP. The term "basic authentication" has been used to describe clear text name and password authentication of just about anything since long before HTTP even existed.

Comment: Could you provide any reference for that?

Comment: I don't feel the need to provide a reference for what is, or at least should be, common knowledge. I realise you're only young but even so you must have come across the term before without it referring to HTTP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]'d